# como alterar o formato da data para d/m/a no php wamp serve

Tags: php, html, wampserver

criei um sistema de cadastro e consultas de dados para o cartório em que trabalho, porém, as datas estão sendo exibidas no formato a/m/d e quero alterar para o formato nacional, mas não sei como fazer. alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Mostre o código onde tenta exibir as datas. Provavelmente é só uma questão de formatar corretamente logo antes de exibir.

Answer (score 0):

Com `PHP`:

```
$sua_data_atual='2018-05-19';
echo date('d/m/Y' strtotime($sua_data_atual));
```

Retona `19/05/2018`.

> [Referência da função **date()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)
>
> [Referência da função **strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)